# Discord py mute command specifying reason without time

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

So I made a mute command and converted it to an optional tempmute yesterday, it worked fine except for when I specified a reason and no time. Obviously that would create a problem but sadly I could not figure out how to fix it. i.e: N?mute user time reason works but N?mute user reason doesn't. If I don't specify the reason nor time it mutes them for 2 years. I want to be able to perm mute people with a reason and also temp mute people with a reason (already works). Hereby the code:

```
@commands.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
async def mute(self, ctx, member: discord.Member, time="670d", *, reason="no reason provided"):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted")
    admin = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Admin")
    mod = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Moderator")
    guild = ctx.guild
    pfp = member.avatar_url
    time_convert = {"s":1, "m":60, "h":3600,"d":86400}
    tempmute= int(time[0]) * time_convert[time[-1]]
    if admin in member.roles or mod in member.roles:
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Mute failed", description="Staff cannot be muted.", color=0xff4654)
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
        return
    if role in member.roles:
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Mute failed", description="**{0}** is already muted!".format(member), color=0xff4654)
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
    if role not in guild.roles:
        perms = discord.Permissions(send_messages=False, speak=False)
        await guild.create_role(name="Muted", permissions=perms)
        await member.add_roles(role, reason=reason) #User muted
        embed = discord.Embed(title="User muted!", description="**{0}** was succesfully muted by **{1}** for **{2}**.".format(member, ctx.message.author, reason), color=0xff4654)
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed) 
        channel = discord.utils.get(guild.channels, name="logs")
        embed = discord.Embed(title=" ", description="**{0}** was muted by **{1}**. Reason: **{2}**".format(member, ctx.message.author, reason), color=0xff4654)
        embed.set_author(name="{0}".format(member), icon_url=pfp)
        await channel.send(embed=embed) #Log
        await asyncio.sleep(tempmute)
        await member.remove_roles(role)
    else:
        await member.add_roles(role, reason=reason) #User muted
        embed = discord.Embed(title="User muted!", description="**{0}** was succesfully muted by **{1}** for **{2}**.".format(member, ctx.message.author, reason), color=0xff4654)
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed) 
        channel = discord.utils.get(guild.text_channels, name="logs") 
        embed = discord.Embed(title=" ", description="<@{0}> was muted by <@{1}>. Reason: **{2}**".format(member.id, ctx.message.author.id, reason), color=0xff4654)
        embed.set_author(name="{0}".format(member), icon_url=pfp)
        await channel.send(embed=embed) #Log
        await asyncio.sleep(tempmute)
        await member.remove_roles(role)
```

I tried doing time: Optional[int] as someone else suggested but alas it broke it entirely.

Answer (score 0):

To answer bluntly, there isn't a nice way of doing this. What I recommend is that you split the command into two separate ones, `mute` and `tempmute`.

If you really do want it as one function, you could do something like this:

```py
import re

async def mute(self, ctx, member: discord.Member, *options):
    if len(options) == 2: # User specified date and reason
        expiry, reason = options
    if len(options) == 1: # User specified one of the above so we need to find out which
        if re.match(r"\d+\D", options[0]):
           # Regex to check for one or more digit then a single non-digit
           expiry = options[0]
           reason = None
        else:
            expiry = None
            reason = options[0]
```

On a slightly unrelated note, you should not do `await asyncio.sleep(tempmute)`. Long sleeps are innacurate and if the bot restarts, the person will never be unmuted. You should create a database with `datetime`s of when the user should be unmuted and have a looping task which queries the database and unmutes users when their time is up.